# Binding column filter to converted value

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, telerik, radgrid

```
 So there is a data model with 2 properties: first name and last name.
```

I'm using custom converter to present this value 
"last name, first name" with logic behind it, that whenever one of the properties is null, converter returns null.
In this situation i also want a telerik filter on column but there is a problem bacause don't bind to converted value but to raw data.

Is there any way to handle this, and have both converted string and filter that is  bind to it?

Here's code xaml/silverlight:

```
<RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}">

<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FirstLastNameConverter}}" /> 

</RadGridView>
```

Default telerik is not shown because binding here is to whole person object

And Person model (cannot change that or make wrapper around it):

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And how would such a ColumnFilter look like in markup? I know (and loathe) some of the telerik controls but nerver used or seen the columnFilter you are mentioning.

Comment: @Martin By saying telerik filter i mean the standard default one from radgridview [pic of that filter](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/features/images/RadGridView_FunctionalOverview_Filtering_1.png)

Comment: Well and how would you declare in the xaml markup that such a filter shall be visible for your DataColumn "Name"?

Comment: @Martin I  don't have to declare it, it's enabled by default but there is a property FilterMemberPath, where i can bind filtering to specific binding, but this doesn't solve a problem because i want to filter not only to first name or last but on both.

Comment: You could add a third property to your item type that combines firstName and lastName in the way your converter does now.

Comment: @Martin Unfortunately i cannot change this type.

Comment: And can you wrap it with your own type?

Comment: @Marton Nope i can't so this need to be done on view layer.

Comment: Well you can introduce your own item wrapper types as part of your own custom control implementation, so it is part of the viewlayer then. There are many controls that wrap items in specialized wrappertypes in order to achieve their intended behavior.

Comment: @Martin i can't change my type and make wrapper to it, can you  write this custom control implementation to situation i described above?

Comment: Post the markup you use to bind items to your RadGridView and post your item type.

Comment: @Martin i posted markup and type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter to wrap each item in a custom `PersonWrapper` type:

```
<RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection,
    Converter={StaticResource ItemWrappingConverter}}">...</...>
```

and code

```
public class ItemWrappingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object param, CultureInfo cultur)
    {
        var persons = value as IEnumerable<Person>;
        if (persons == null) return null;
        return persons.Select(person => new PersonWrapper()
        {
            Person = person,
            FullName = GetFullName(person.FirstName, person.LastName)
        } );
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetT, object param, CultureInfo culture)
    { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}

public class PersonWrapper
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But what if i have additional properties in this Person etc. address, phone number and other columns?

Comment: Changed it slightly. You can use any path like "Person.Address" or "Person.PhoneNumber" etc.

Comment: I did it other way but this approach will work too, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

So problem was solved another way. Instead of using converter, I used telerik expression. So this way raw binding is made to expression and filter is working fine. Here's an [example](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/expression-column.html).